# just boot in recovery mode htc one xl

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, htc-one-xl

Well, I have a htc onexl at&t (evita) bootloader unlock and custom recovery TWRP 
when i try to turn on my phone he just boot in recovery, i can go to bootloader but i cant boot in system, is not a boot loop, he just go directly to recovery

This is what i did:

- Unlock bootloader
- Install custom recovery TWRP 2.6.3.0
- Then I try to restart the phone and when he turn on he go directly to
  recovery

Answer (score 0):

On TWRP recovery, tap `Reboot` and then `System`